# How do I redefine a #defined value?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to create a bash script that will change the value of the following to the value I input to the command-line:

```
#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 10
#endif
```

Is there any way I can change the value of SIZE?

Comment: you want to change the source code using `sed`? Is it related to C at all? don't you want to pass `-DSIZE=30` to change it using compilation switches?

Comment: as i understand it, you want to change the value of `SIZE` from 10 to say 20 at run time?  if so the answer is no.  Preprocessor commands (of which `#define` is one) are handled early in the compilation process.  What happens with a `#define` is that every occurrence of the string `SIZE` is replaced by 10 even before the code is parsed.  What you could do is have a variable (say `size`) that is initialized by default to 10, and then process the command line arguments and modify the variable as needed.

Comment: The best way to do this is to put all such constant in separate headers, then edit/generate those headers as needed. Using GCC features to generate pre-processor constants is a bad idea, strive for portability and standard C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `-DSIZE=30` to GCC when compiling the program, then `SIZE` will be defined as `30` right from the start. Then, since the code shown in the question checks if it's already defined, it won't be defined as `10`.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know more about -DSIZE for GCC.
What would you recommend that I search on Google to find out more about this?

Comment: @MasterGL It's in the ["Controlling the Preprocessor"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) section. I Googled "gcc command line", then used the index on that page.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate every one of your help :)